# How to call a function without its arguments?

Tags: python, firebase, kivy

I am trying to call the  `def listener` function but im new to firebase streaming so I don't know how the  `event` argument works and I cant call the function without the argument. anyone who knows anyway I could call the method. I would appreciate it.

```
class Notifications(Screen):
    notificationslist = ObjectProperty(None)

 def listener(self, event):
        notifications_screen = self.manager.get_screen('notif')
        print(event.event_type)  # can be 'put' or 'patch'
        print(event.path)  # relative to the reference, it seems
        print(event.data)  # new data at /reference/event.path. None if deleted
        notifications = event.data
        if notifications.items() == None:
            return
        else:
            for key, value in notifications.items():
                thevalue = value
                notifications_screen.notificationslist.adapter.data.extend([value[0:17] + '\n' + value[18:]])
                print(thevalue)
                id = (thevalue[thevalue.index("(") + 1:thevalue.rindex(")")])
                print(id)
```

Comment: What do you expect the function to do if you don't pass it any arguments?

Comment: This looks like something where you don't call `listener` explicitly; you provide it as a callback for something *else* to call with an appropriate argument.

Comment: The argument `event` is used in all the function. In this case, it seems you cannot just "forget" this argument, since all the function works on the attributes of `event`

Comment: @RomainF do you know about any other way I can it ?

Comment: If you want to call this function you need an `event` with the correct attributes including `event_type`, `path`, `data`... The question would be why do you need to call this function? I would agree with @chepner that `listener` should not be called by the user, but is used internally by other functions

Comment: @RomainF can you please show me an example?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how this `event` is internally created or managed :( The calling function might manage this `event`. If this `listener` function is run by a code, you can look at the call stack to find the caller and inspect it

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [default argument](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-arguments-in-python/) in Python if you wish to call your function without passing parameters.

The function parameter takes the default value if the parameter is not supplied during the function call.

```
class Notifications(Screen):
    notificationslist = ObjectProperty(None)

 def listener(self, event = None):
        notifications_screen = self.manager.get_screen('notif')
        print(event.event_type)  # can be 'put' or 'patch'
        print(event.path)  # relative to the reference, it seems
        print(event.data)  # new data at /reference/event.path. None if deleted
        notifications = event.data
        if notifications.items() == None:
            return
        else:
            for key, value in notifications.items():
                thevalue = value
                notifications_screen.notificationslist.adapter.data.extend([value[0:17] + '\n' + value[18:]])
                print(thevalue)
                id = (thevalue[thevalue.index("(") + 1:thevalue.rindex(")")])
                print(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def functionName(arg = None):
   ''' Your Code '''
   return
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: @theTinMan im trying to run the code forever and I don't know how to do that

Comment: @theTinMan want to run it, that only when there is new data in the stream, the notifications list update. please any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: The person posting it needs to explain the code, why it's useful, and at the same time can explain how to make it do what you want. That's how we are supposed to answer questions on SO. If the question doesn't help then feel free to down-vote it.